# Resistor in series with a Diode conducting conditions

Tags: resistors, diodes

When having a resistor(R) in series with a diode(D), i keep seeing that in order for the diode to be conducting electricity the voltage on the branch R+D should be higher than the diodes potential.
But what happens to the voltage drop on the resistor, why doesn't it get calculated?

Comment: I assume with *diodes potential* you mean forward voltage, don't you?

Comment: Yes, i think that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to make sure the voltage across R + D is higher than forward voltage of the diode, because the resistor has to take what is left; unlike the diode a resistor conducts even at voltages close to 0V.